# A.M. is two times G.M.

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics, ratio

> If the A.M. between $a$ and $b$ is twice as great as their G.M., show that $a:b=(2+\sqrt3):(2-\sqrt3)$.

My attempt: $$\frac{a+b}{2}=2\sqrt{ab}$$

$$\sqrt\frac{a}{b}+\sqrt\frac{b}{a}=4$$

Let $\sqrt\frac{a}{b}=x$. So,

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=4$$
$$x^2-4x+1=0$$

$$x=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-4}}{2}$$
$$x=2\pm\sqrt3$$

So, $a:b=4+3\pm4\sqrt3=7\pm4\sqrt3$

Comment: Looks fine. $    $

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. Just note that $$(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})=1$$

So $$a:b = (2+\sqrt3)^2:1 = (2+\sqrt3):(2-\sqrt3)$$

Comment: oh, thanks. Does that mean the answer can also be $(2-\sqrt3):(2+\sqrt3)$?

Comment: @Ramit The formulas for the AM and GM are symmetric in $a$ and $b$, so exchanging $a$ and $b$ gives the same result.